# How do I use the hue argument in the plot fuctions for counting the specific number of observation of a label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I basically have two problems which are very simple yet I'm stuck as I'm not use to work with stadistics in python.

The first problems is that I have a dataset with a large number of rows and a few labels, and I'm interested in two of them. I want to plot a Bar Chart (in any of the two ways seem below) that plots me the number of rows that satifies belonging to a particular class of the first label divided by the class of the second label. For example if in the Group A there's 160 rows and each of them 40 if also for Series 1, I want it plotted like below (there's a link in an image)

```
         Group  Series
0   Group A Series 2    
1   Group B Series 1    
2   Group B Series 5    
3   Group A Series 4    
0   Group A Series 1    
1   Group B Series 3    
2   Group B Series 3    
3   Group A Series 2
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfBSA.png)

The second problems is that I would also like to know if is there any fuction that given two labels, for each class of the first label, tells me the percentaje of each of labels of the second column. Like in the second question but instead of visually I want it numerically. The output would be something like

```
Group A : 24% Series 1, 17% Series 2, 11% Series 3...
Group B: 27% Series 1, 13% Series 2, 10% Series 3...
```

I've tried the plotting with the hue argument but I don't know how do I do for counting the number of observations.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Show us what you've tried. If you're not actually asking about plotting (_instead of visually I want it numerically_), it'd be something like: `df.groupby(col1)[col2].value_counts()`?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. My second problem is solved. Can you please with me with plotting it as the image I posted? I know it is with the hue argument but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: This is the graph I would like to get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfBSA.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe `sns.countplot(data=dataset, x="Group", hue="Series", dodge=True)`?  Or `sns.histplot(data=dataset, x="Group", hue="Series", discrete=True, multiple='fill')`? See also [How to scale Y axis to 100 percent for each categorical value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234584/seaborn-how-to-scale-y-axis-to-100-percent-for-each-categorical-value)